# Gutenberg - How to access custom redux store data in PHP

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom redux store using `createReduxStore` in my Gutenberg block and I need to access some of the store data on the server side in php.

Let's say my store has a value called css which I would access in javascript like this

```js
wp.data.select('mystore/css').getCss();
```

Now I need to access this data on the server side using PHP so I can save a file using the filesystem.

How would I go about accessing the store css data?